# How can I apply exceptions to window decoration on compiz?

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04

Back in the previous releases, I used the compiz plugins "window decoration" and "window rules" to have a transparent, sticky, unmovable gnome-terminal acting as a wallpaper. The trick was to create a profile with a permanent title (transparent) and then use the filter `title=transparent` and `!title=transparent` in the different plugin rules.

The result looked like this:

[image]

After the upgrade, I've noticed that the window decoration rule no longer applies. Aparently, window decorations are now managed by the unity plugin and not the gtk-window-decorator, which I suppose was necessary to create the locally integrated menus. Now the terminal looks like this:

[image]

If I try to force the "window decoration" plugin, it asks me to disable the unity plugin, and then all the desktop crashes. So my question is if there's a workaround to force compiz not to use decorations on this specific window. Maybe with some sort of parameter when launching the terminal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An oldie but goody that still works to deal with window decorations is devilspie

[image]

### how to

Install devilspie:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Then create a new folder in your home folder:

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie
```

Create a new file in this folder called `terminal.ds` and paste the following:

```
(if
    (is (application_name) "Terminal")
    (begin
       (undecorate)
       (geometry "1024x300+4+450")
    ) )
```

The key part here is `(undecorate)` to remove the window decoration for the terminal application.

`(geometry)` is used to control the location and size of the application, in this case 1024 in length, 300 pixels high and placed in the position 4 x 450

When testing, edit the file, then run `devilspie` to see the changes enacted.

When you are happy, just put `nohup devilspie &` as a startup application to run on login.

Obviously you'll lose the titlebar if you intend to use locally integrated menus.  If you stick with global menus then this works very well.

More information about devilspie can be [found here](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie).

#### finally

Dont forget that you are still able to move the terminal window around the screen - just use the shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to enable the window move capability and drag the mouse point around to position the terminal.

---

Just in-case you are not already aware of the option - to set the transparency of the terminal, use `edit - profile preferences` and select the Transparent Background option

[image]

Comment: Simply superb :-)

Comment: Great! I found about devilspie but didn't have any idea how to use it, thanks!

Comment: In case somebody was using this the same way I do, I've modified a little your config, so it only applies to a terminal specific profile and not all terminals. The result is like this: (if
    (is (window_name) "transparent")
    (begin
       (undecorate)
     ) )

Comment: do you think this could help to differentiate windows owned by root? http://askubuntu.com/questions/486476/is-there-some-way-to-make-windows-owned-by-root-sudo-look-different-from-norma

Comment: I think there's a plugin in compiz to include the "root" word in the window title when an application runs with privileges, you could try that and combine it with devilspie.