# is there some way to make windows owned by root (sudo) look different from normal user ones?

Tags: sudo, window-decoration

I run `sudo gedit` but it looks exactly like another `gedit` I have open with normal user...

Any way to make it look diferent? but I dont mean tweaking each application preferences like background color of text; I mean the window decorations; I am unable to find a good way to work around that.

I dont want just the background because I like it dark, and at least on gedit there is not much options; anyway other applications may not have such option.

PS.: I actually run `sudo -i gedit` because without `-i` it overwrites and messes my normal user recent files history...

Folowing @Jobin `gksudo` tip, I got this result with `kate`:
[image]
The image below the other is from `gksudo kate`, the above one is normal user; so basically, the window decoration of title bar did not change, both remained "radiance", but the buttons and the background are completely different themes! Unfortunately it seems kate has specific settings for at least the background color :(, I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: You should actually be using `gksudo gedit` instead of `sudo gedit`.

Comment: @Jobin, I find that `gksudo` is not installed by default in Ubuntu 14.04. According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/313828/why-is-pkexec-preferred-over-gksudo-for-graphical-applications, we have to make `pkexec` work for GUI applications, individually. So perhaps the user should install `gksu` (which provides `gksudo`).

Comment: @muru `gksudo` seems better than `pkexec` because it prevents loosing password prompt focus!

Comment: @Jobin `kate` looks a huge lot different when using `gksudo`! but gedit did not look too much different, but I think that may lead to something! :)

Comment: @muru just found `pkexec` seems safer at [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo), but `pkexec kate` cant connect to X :/

Comment: to make `pkexec` run properly look at http://askubuntu.com/a/332847/46437

Comment: @AquariusPower so have you used `pkexec` or `gksudo` finally? Did theming work? Usually, my own GTK is themed, so distinguishing apps running as root is easy for me.

Comment: @muru I use unity, so compiz decorates the windows, I am getting used to the unity Hud and would prefer to not disable it, also ccsm has many cool things like woobly :); so basically, unity decorations are overriding any user preferences, so the current logged in user is the opted decorations for all windows :(

Comment: I think it's possible to turn off window decorations to specific windows in compiz according to http://superuser.com/a/195481

Comment: @muru I checked at "ubuntu unity plugin" at ccsm on the tab "decorations", unfortunately there was no filter to act over specific windows :(

Answer (score 1):

You could open the Settings for `root`:

```
sudo -i unity-control-center
```

And then change the appearance settings. `gnome-tweak-tool` should work too - and give slightly more control. I haven't used `unity-tweak-tool`, but from its [description](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool), it seems to offer the most options.

Comment: I am trying to put root theme as "ambiance" and normal user as "radiance", with all these tweakers, such settings are saved on root but when actually opening any app (gedit, kate) with sudo/gksudo the theme is still "radiance" :/

Comment: at my op I found that the buttons and background could be completely different, I am still trying all these tweaks to find where it is configured, unfortunately I see no much options there.. still looking!